# SQL / Apex - Variable number / character confusion

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure I need to feed a number into in order to generate some thumbnails.

I'm trying to automatically update the value every time a new row is inserted but I'm having trouble with the code.

```
DECLARE

varInt NUMBER :='SELECT MAX(IMAGE_ID) FROM IMAGES';

begin
create_blob_thumbnail(varInt);
end;
```

I get the error *'ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error'*

If I run the query **SELECT MAX(IMAGE_ID) FROM IMAGES**, it returns the last row ID I created just as it should.

The **create_blob_thumbnail(varInt)** procedure works fine if I manually put in a number.

Searched for ages and tried a lot of different things, anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Worked it out!

    DECLARE

    varInt NUMBER;

    BEGIN

    SELECT MAX(IMAGE_ID) into varInt FROM IMAGES;
    create_blob_thumbnail(varInt);

    END;

Comment: Post the answer to your question as a real answer and then accept it. Nothing wrong with that! This question then won't end up as being unanswered.

Comment: Haha, sorry new to the site didn't realise I could do that! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out!

```
DECLARE

varInt NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT MAX(IMAGE_ID) into varInt FROM IMAGES;
create_blob_thumbnail(varInt);

END;
```